# webpack style-loader + css-loader not importing

Tags: webpack

I have Webpack set up and it's transforming jsx and doing HMR just fine, but then when I tried to add CSS to my javascript files by adding to the config

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        loader: 'babel', 
        exclude: /node_modules|bower_modules/ 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: 'style!css', 
        exclude:/node_modules|bower_modules/
      },
    ]
  },
```

and in my test.css

```
.htmlPreview{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and finally in my invoice.jsx

```
import styles from './test.css';
console.log(styles)
```

it logs undefined. The setup is pretty simple, but could anyone see any thing that I might have missed?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
npm install css-loader style-loader --save-dev
```

then update your loader:

```
{ 
  test: /\.css$/, 
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
}
```